# Watir - text_field - watermarked/pre-populated text concatenation

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I am a relatively new user of ruby and have witnessed the following sporadic anomaly with entering text into text fields with pre-populated (or watermarked) text.

I have a login page with Email address and password fields. 
The Email address field has some pre-populated text which says 'Enter your email address here'
When the user clicks in the text field, the text disappears ready to accept the actual input.

However, on *some* runs of my ruby/watir scripts I'm finding that the value I wish to enter (using browser.text_field(:id,'name').set 'mylogin') simply gets concatenated with the pre-populated text (I.e. so I see 'Enter your email address heremylogin') and on other runs it does what I expect and just enters 'mylogin')

So far, I"ve only been trying this on Firefox 9.0/Mac OSX so don't know whether it's a peculiarity of the browser, os, or indeed the site under test. The html of the fields in question look like this:

```
<input name="ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$TextBox_email" type="text" id="ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_TextBox_email" style="color:#0B404E;border-color:#A4A4A4;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;font-family:Arial;font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;width:318px;padding: 4px 10px;" class="watermarked" autocomplete="off">

<input type="hidden" name="ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$TextBoxWatermarkExtender_email_ClientState" id="ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_TextBoxWatermarkExtender_email_ClientState">
```

Is there an alternative way of inserting text into this field without triggering this anomaly?

Thanks in advance

D

Answer (score 0):

If it's a "sometimes it does this, sometimes it does that" issue, I'd go with it being a timing problem.

Try running the same code through IRB ( http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/IRB )

e.g. `browser.text_field(:id => "emailAddress").set("my.email.address@whatever.com")`

If that works, refresh the page and do it again with `browser.refresh`

If it consistently inputs the correct email address using IRB, it's most probably a timing issue.

Test by adding a small sleep to your script just before putting the email address into the field, e.g.

```
sleep 10
browser.text_field(:id => "emailAddress").set("my.email.address@whatever.com")
```

If that works, something's changing on your site between the page loading and between when watir interacts with that field.  Find out what, and wait for that to happen.

Potentially with something like `browser.wait_until{browser.text_field(:id => "emailAddress").value == "The placeholder text"`

Answer (score 0):

There is likely some client side code that clears the field.  if you view the HTML you might find it.  if I was guessing I'd try 'onfocus'' first

when watir fills in the field a lot of things happen very rapidly and the client side code may not get a chance to clear the prior contents.

what I would do is use irb and the `.fire_event` method to see if you can fire an event that causes the field to clear  e.g.

```
browser.text_field(:id => "emailAddress").fire_event('onfocus')
```

if you find one that clears the field, then try putting that line ahead of the line in your script that sets the value

another option would be to try `.value=` instead of `.set`